# Erroneous replacement with ren command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a script for Windows cmd to correct file names in a directory. The `ren` command has been working to correct the file names in different cases. But in one case something weird is happening.

> `ren cl_cjl_cl_crmt_* cjl_cl_crmt_*`

It will rename files from  `cl_cjl_cl_crmt_example.sql` to `cjl_cl_crmt_mt.sql` and keep an extra `_mt`

It seems to omit the last 2 characters in the replacement. The same thing happens when I try to rename it somewhat differently using `ren cl_cjl_cl_* cjl_cl_*`

It will rename files from  `cl_cjl_cl_crmt_example.sql` to  `cjl_cl_cl_crmt_mt.sql` and keep an extra `_cl`

How can I get the proper behaviour for the `ren` command. Or what is a better option

Comment: Better would be in a batch file `for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%I in ('dir cl_cjl_cl_crmt_* /A-D /B 2^>nul') do ren "%%I_%%J" "%%J"` and `for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %I in ('dir cl_cjl_cl_crmt_* /A-D /B 2^>nul') do @ren "%I_%J" "%J"` directly in a command prompt window. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and `dir /?` and read both output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page.

Comment: Please take a look at [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) for more information on your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I do not believe the new file names you mention, they will for sure be of the same lengths as the respective old file names.

When you are looking at the source and target names in detail you will find out that the additional `mt` or `cl` portion is just a copy of the characters from the source name at the same position:

```cmd
ren cl_cjl_cl_crmt_* cjl_cl_crmt_*
```

> ```cmd
> source name:   cl_cjl_cl_crmt_example.sql
>                            ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
> target name:   cjl_cl_crmt_mt_example.sql
> ```

```cmd
ren cl_cjl_cl_* cjl_cl_*
```

> ```cmd
> source name:   cl_cjl_cl_crmt_example.sql
>                       ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
> target name:   cjl_cl_cl_crmt_example.sql
> ```

There is no correlation between the source and target names, hence any part of the target name is not linked in any way to that same part in the source name; you can prove that with the following example:

```cmd
ren cl_* 12345??89*
```

> ```cmd
> source name:   cl_cjl_cl_crmt_example.sql
>                     ↓↓  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
> target name:   12345l_89_crmt_example.sql
> ```

If you just want to remove `cl_` prefix, given that this part is always exactly three characters long, you could make use of the following quirk:

```cmd
ren "cl_*" "///*"
```

The quotation marks are mandatory here, but they are anyway good practice.

All this is described in this Super User post: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/a/475875/489381)